# Vim status line is not updated immediately in Linux

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using [Powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/) but all I saying is also true for regular VIM status line.
In Windows when I'm going to the paste mode(paste toggle) I immediately see this in status line - red bar with "PASTE" in it. But in Linux(Ubuntu) I need to make some moves(j, k, w, b, etc.) to see the result, before any moves - the status line is not updating.
P.S. The same effect I can get in windows with using [Shell.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3123) plugin and going to the fullscreen mode

Comment: What version of vim? 7.2? 7.3? Are you using gVim or terminal vim?

Comment: 7.2 and 7.3 I tried in both. The same in gVim and in terminal

Comment: Under windows I tried only in 7.3

Comment: Does 'set ttyfast' help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the link in @DaniloSousa's answer no longer works, I thought I'd add in what works for me (probably pretty close to that solution):

```
nnoremap <silent> <F2> :set paste!<CR>
set pastetoggle=<F2>
```

This will toggle paste on/off via  in both normal and insert modes and immediately update the status in Powerline.  I don't know if it'll work without Powerline; possibly depends on the state of `showmode` and/or what you've defined `statuline` as.

Comment: yeah, basically what I do in my .vimrc :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried use `paste!` instead of `pastetoggle` as Lokaltog suggests in issue [#103](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/issues/103#issuecomment-4302754)?

Worked for me!